# Prove/disprove the following:

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I'm given the following problem:

Prove that if $f$ is negative and increasing between $a$ and $b$, then the left Riemann sum is an underestimate and the right Riemann sum is an overestimate.

After drawing a graph, I concluded that this statement is false but I do not know how to prove this algebraically. Any pointers?

Comment: It is actually true; you must be confusing something!

Comment: Remember that for functions that are negative, area and integral aren't _quite_ the same thing.

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/277120c505564af2bd5fb0301d03d325.png

Comment: It seems to me that there is an overestimate for the area of a left reimann sum in this graph, or is is that the area of a negative function is negative, meaning that it is less area in the end?

Comment: @Questionasker The left sum overestimates the area, but underestimates the integral.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

Consider the partition $[x_0, x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]$ of $[a, b]$ where $x_0 = a, x_n = b$;

Notice that $f(x_0) \leq f(x_1) \leq \cdots \leq f(x_{n-1}) \leq f(x_n)$. (the $\leq$ may be exchanged by $<$ if the problem statement means that $f$ is **strictly** increasing.

Are you able to write the expressions for the left and right riemman sums of that partition?